# Función de javascript que regrese el valor de una funcion y ocuparla en otra

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con una función, necesito ocupar el valor almacenado en la primera función (entrada1) y ocuparlo en la segunda (operacion1) mediante id para que haga la operación y mostrarla en el input (con id sumando1), alguien sabe por que no me esta mostrando nada en la casilla numero 2?

Operacion por id

```
    var num1=0;
    num1 = parseInt(num1);     


    alert("Pagina que registra un numero");



    //Funcion que recibe un numero para hacer operaciones

    function entrada1(num1)
    {

        num1 = prompt("Escriba el primer numero, sera multiplicado x 3");     
        document.getElementById('numero1').value = num1;
        document.getElementById('imprime1').value = num1; 
        return num1;  
    }


    //Funcion que multiplica por 3 del primer numero ingresado en la primera casilla

    function operacion1(num1)
    {

        document.getElementById('sumando1') = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero1')

    }

     </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
        <p> 
            <!--Casilla numero 1-->
            Numero ingresado: <input id="numero1" onChange="entrada1()" type="text" readonly="readonly"> 
            <input type="button" onClick="entrada1()" value="Ingresar">
        </p> 
        <p>
            <!--Casilla numero 2-->
            Numero con su resultado: <input onChange="operacion1()" id="sumando1" type="text" readonly="readonly">  
        </p>

        <p>
            <!--Casilla numero 3-->
            Imprime numero: <input id="imprime1" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" readonly="readonly">

        </p>
         </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estás usando adecuadamente las propiedades de los `inputs` ni los eventos. La llamada a `document.getElementById('sumando1')` retorna un [Elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element) por lo que si quieres cambiar su valor tienes que usar la propiedad [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

El evento [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) no se dispara nunca porque tus `inputs` son de sólo lectura y este evento sólo se desencadena cuando

> Cuando el elemento pierde el foco luego que su valor sea cambiado pero no actualizado aún

Si quieres usar el retorno de la función como entrada debes llamar a la segunda usando como argumento la primera. Ej.

```
segunda(primera());
```

En tu caso sería `operacion1(entrada1())`, todo eso en el evento onclick que es donde se desencadena la acción de calcular.

Quedaría así

```js
function entrada1() {
  num1 = prompt("Escriba el primer numero, sera multiplicado x 3");
  document.getElementById('numero1').value = num1;
  document.getElementById('imprime1').value = num1;
  return num1;
}


//Funcion que multiplica por 3 del primer numero ingresado en la primera casilla

function operacion1(num1) {

  document.getElementById('sumando1').value = parseInt(num1, 10) * 3;

}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <!--Casilla numero 1-->
    Numero ingresado:
    <input id="numero1" type="text" readonly="readonly">
    <input type="button" onClick="operacion1(entrada1())" value="Ingresar">
  </p>
  <p>
    <!--Casilla numero 2-->
    Numero con su resultado:
    <input id="sumando1" type="text" readonly="readonly">
  </p>

  <p>
    <!--Casilla numero 3-->
    Imprime numero:
    <input id="imprime1" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" readonly="readonly">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: En la segunda función, en la parte de "parseInt(num1, 10) * 3;" no se por que agregaste el diez pero aun asi funciona muy bien, gracias por responder!

Comment: El 10 significa que es un Entero en base 10. Lo cual es redundante ya que si no le pasas nada funciona igual.

Comment: A perfecto!, muchas gracias otra vez!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo "Lo cual es redundante" Esto no para nada cierto, lee la referencia de [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) la  cual especifica claramente en la sección del `radix` "**Siempre** especifique este parámetro para eliminar la confusión del lector y para garantizar un comportamiento predecible. Diferentes implementaciones producen resultados diferentes cuando la base no es especificada, **usualmente** toma un valor por defecto de 10". cc://@Pacon

Answer (score 1):

porque no le estás pasando el valor del casillero y porque no le estás cambiando la propiedad `value`:

```
document.getElementById('sumando1') = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero1'));
```

La forma correcta es :

```
document.getElementById('sumando1').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero1').value);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuestas!